# How to migrate indexes to a new cluster in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, cluster-computing

For today, I have a cluster of elasticsearch containing two weeks of indexes and in few days, we will receive new machines so we will need to migrate all indexes into the new machines. For migration I have a made scenario;

- I will have back up of the indexes
- I will conenct new machines to the cluster
- Will wait for machines to syncronise
- Lastly I will shutdown all old machines.

So I hope I will migrate the old cluster into new cluster. Do you think this scenario is enough or I need to add some more steps ?

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've already migrated our data accros several Elasticsearch clusters several times, and here is how we proceed :

- each node has a specific tag (defined in configuration file, like
  `node.mytag: mytagvalue`)
- we connect our new machines to the cluster
- we use shard allocation clustering, and exclude tag of our old
  machines, so all data are automatically migrated to new machine (see
  [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/index-modules-allocation.html#index-modules-allocation))
- once it's done, we shutdown old machines

if you have not already defined tag for your nodes (would require a restart on old machines, so can be inconvenient), you can exclude IP address, name, id or host name, respectively

Comment: is there a way to do it without restarting machines ?

Comment: yes, do not use tag, but available attributes => "Additionally, special attribute names called _ip, _name, _id and _host can be used to match by node ip address, name, id or host name, respectively." (from doc)